# Connecting to a MS Access database

Tags: php

Someone asked me to do some research to achieve the following result, maybe you guys can help me out an suggest me some tips.

We have a local server and there are different 'jobs' on it ( in a MS Access ) Database.

Now we want to create a platform where other users can check their "job status" with different parameters ( field names etc ) from the MS Access database.

I am looking for the best practice, how to connect to this database from everywhere in the world. I already did some research and found the following links:

http://phpmaster.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

- How can I connect between a web-application and that MS Access database
- Can I update it realtime
- What kind of protocol does the servers has to support to intereact with a website?
- Currently the server can be reached from outside via a VPN connection.

A piece of code I've already tried :

```
try{
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=Custos_TAB.accdb;Uid=Admin");
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I received the following error : "could not find driver".

Comment: Fine that you tried some code snippet. Any reason why you don't post the result or problem you ran into? And great you found those descriptions you referenced. Any reason why you ask the questios already answered in there here again?

Comment: You need to enable the `pdo_odbc` driver in your `php.ini` file

Comment: I've added already : 
ini_set('extension', 'php_pdo_odbc.dll');

Comment: I would suggest that if you get that error then you have NOT actually enabled the driver. Does that dll exist? did you restart the web server after enabling it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming you have the PDO odbc driver installed and enabled on the web server.

```
$user='Admin';
$password='';
$mdbFilename="Custos_TAB.accdb";

    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM [tblHere]";
    $rs=odbc_exec($connection,$sql);

    //do stuff here

    odbc_close($connection);
```

or

```
 $user='Admin';
    $password='';
/*if you have a path here such as c:\db\Custos_TAB.accdb, make sure to use double
  backslashes, (i.e "c:\\db\\Custos_TAB.accdb")*/
    $mdbFilename="Custos_TAB.accdb";


    $conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename;Uid=$user='Admin';Pwd=$password;");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Stop running services first (if there's any)
- Open the `php.ini` file and uncomment the extension for `php_pdo_odbc`
- Start services again (if needed)
- Make sure you correctly locate your database in `Dbq=Custos_TAB.accdb`

`//Just an example in my case`

`Dbq=C:\Users\Server\Documents\Db1.accdb`